# Showing solution to ODE is defined up to infinite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

**Question**
Consider the system
$$x'(t)=-x(t)^{3}+y(t)^{2}$$
$$y'(t)=\cos(x(t)y(t)^{2})$$
with initial conditions $x(0)=1, y(0)=2$. Let $(a,b)$ be the maximal interval that the solution is defined and show $b=\infty$.

**Partial Progress**
An attempt for a proof by contradiction. Let $b<\infty$ so for some finite $b$
we know $||x(t)||\to\infty$ as $t\to b$. Since $y'(t)$ is a trigonometric function with the given initial condition, we know $|y'(t)|\leq 1$ and $|y(t)|\leq t+2$. This doesn't seem to substitute nicely into the equation for $x'(t)$ or $x(t)$ to form a finite upper bound.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found, $|y(t)-2|\le |t|$, or weaker, $|y(t)|\le 2+|t|$.

Now do not look at any potential solution but just the vector field for the first equation. If $x\ge(2+|t|)$ then
$$
-x^3+y^2\le -(8+12|t|+6|t|^2+|t|^3)^2+(4+2|t|+|t|^2)\le -4
$$
Similarly, for $x\le -1$ one gets
$$
-x^3+y^2\ge1
$$
This establishes the wedge $-1\le x\le 2+|t|$ as a trapping region for the dynamic of the $x$ component for $t\ge 0$. As the IVP starts within that wedge, it stays within that wedge in forward time. There can be no divergence to infinity in finite time, the solution must exist up to $b=+\infty$.

Comment: Could you say more about looking at the vector field instead of potential solutions? And how you got the inequality for $x\geq (2+|t|)$?

Comment: The basic idea is that for $x$ large enough the derivative for $x$ points towards zero. You know how large $y$ can get, so you only need to set $x$ a little or considerably larger than $|y|^{2/3}$ so that $x^3$ dominates $y^2$. So you could use $x\ge (3+t)^{2/3}$ or use the above linear boundary.

Comment: Okay I see your point about for $x$ large $x'(t)$ is negative. But using the weaker bound, how do you get $-(8+12|t|+6|t|^{2}+|t|^{3})^{2}+(4+2|t|+|t|^{2})\leq 4$? Or the value $x\leq -1$ to conclude $-x^{3}+y^{2}\geq 1$? Sorry for so many follow-ups but could you give a more step by step explanation?

Comment: Because $a^3$ is larger than $a^2$ for $a>1$, and $2+|t|>1$. Or $a^2-a^3<-4$ for $a>2$, which is also the case here.